# android gps distance shows previous record while restart

Tags: android, gps

I have an android application which calculate distance from GPS while walking. First time distance calculation correct. But when I restart application, it shows the previous distance initially, it should be 0.

Here is my activity:

```
public class Gps extends Activity {
TextView display;
Button start;
boolean doubleclick = false;
AnimationDrawable AppNameAnimation;
private boolean enabled;
double currentLon = 0;
double currentLat = 0;
double lastLon = 0;
double lastLat = 0;
double distance;
Animation animRotate;
TextView startStop;

LocationManager lm;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    startStop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_rotate);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!doubleclick) {
                lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                enabled = lm
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (!enabled) {
                    Intent inte = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(inte);
                } else {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            Loclist);
                    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if (loc == null) {
                        display.setText("No GPS location found");
                    } else {
                        // set Current latitude and longitude
                        currentLon = loc.getLongitude();
                        currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
                        Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);

                    }
                    // Set the last latitude and longitude
                    startStop.setText("Stop");
                    lastLat = currentLat;
                    lastLon = currentLon;
                    doubleclick = true;
                }
            } else {
                lm.removeUpdates(Loclist);
                startStop.setText("Start");
                v.clearAnimation();
                doubleclick = false;
                Intent in = new Intent(Gps.this, NextActivity.class);
                // in.putExtra("distance", display.toString());
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}

LocationListener Loclist = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // start location manager
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Get last location
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // Request new location
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);

        // Get new location
        Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // get the current lat and long
        currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
        currentLon = loc.getLongitude();

        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);
        if (lastLat != 0 || lastLon != 0) {
            double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

            double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

            display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            Constant.distance = (String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            start.startAnimation(animRotate);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
}
```

Please help me. It is very important to me.

**Edited Code**

```
public class Gps extends Activity {
TextView display;
Button start;
boolean doubleclick = false;
AnimationDrawable AppNameAnimation;
private boolean enabled;
double currentLon = 0;
double currentLat = 0;
double lastLon = 0;
double lastLat = 0;
double distance;
Animation animRotate;
TextView startStop;

LocationManager lm;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    startStop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_rotate);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!doubleclick) {
                lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                enabled = lm
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (!enabled) {
                    Intent inte = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(inte);
                } else {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            Loclist);
                    Log.e("successss", "111111111111");
                }
            } else {
                lm.removeUpdates(Loclist);
                startStop.setText("Start");
                v.clearAnimation();
                doubleclick = false;
                Intent in = new Intent(Gps.this, NextActivity.class);
                // in.putExtra("distance", display.toString());
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}

LocationListener Loclist = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("successss", "2222222222222");
        // start location manager
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);
        // Get last location

        if(!doubleclick){
        Location loc1 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.e("successss", "33333333333333333");
        if (loc1 == null) {
            display.setText("No GPS location found");
        } else {
            Log.e("successss", "444444444444");
            // set Current latitude and longitude
            currentLon = loc1.getLongitude();
            currentLat = loc1.getLatitude();
            Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);

        }
        Log.e("successss", "5555555555555");
        // Set the last latitude and longitude
        startStop.setText("Stop");
        lastLat = currentLat;
        lastLon = currentLon;
        doubleclick = true;
        }
        Log.e("successss", "66666666666");
        Log.e("Location", "lastLat:" + lastLat);
        Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);
        //Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // Request new location
        //lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);

        // Get new location
        Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // get the current lat and long
        currentLat = loc2.getLatitude();
        currentLon = loc2.getLongitude();

        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);
        if (lastLat != 0 || lastLon != 0) {
            double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

            double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

            display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            Constant.distance = (String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            start.startAnimation(animRotate);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you restart your app, it takes some time for the GPS to get the new location coordinates.

in your code you have this

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);
                    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

so, `loc` is having the `lastKnownLocationValues` from the last run and hence displaying them.

if you dont want to display the last known location values, assign `loc = null` on every restart, but then it will take some time to fetch the first location.

this peculiar behavior is implemented because generally it may happen that your GPS connectivity is lost for a few moments, in that short span you don't want to show the user that the location is null or could not be found, because probably in this small span they haven't travelled too far, and so you display the last known location instead.

EDIT:

remove this code from your else 
and do this is your locationListener

instead of

```
 if (!enabled) {
                    Intent inte = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(inte);
                } else {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            Loclist);
                    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if (loc == null) {
                        display.setText("No GPS location found");
                    } else {
                        // set Current latitude and longitude
                        currentLon = loc.getLongitude();
                        currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
                        Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);

                    }
                    // Set the last latitude and longitude
                    startStop.setText("Stop");
                    lastLat = currentLat;
                    lastLon = currentLon;
                    doubleclick = true;
                }
```

change to

```
 if (!enabled) {
                    Intent inte = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(inte);
                } else {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            Loclist);

                        display.setText("searching for location...");
                    }
```

and then update your textboxes in your `locationListener`'s `onLocationChanged()` method

EDIT:

declare two more variables and a flag

```
private boolean enabled;
double currentLon = 0;
double currentLat = 0;

double prevLon = 0;
double prevLat = 0;
bool firstTime = true;
```

in your onLocationChanged()

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

```
if(!firstTime){
        prevLon = currentLon;
        prevLat = currentLat;

        currentLat = location.getLatitude();
        currentLon = location.getLongitude();

        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(prevLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(prevLon);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);

        ...
        }

else{
       firstTime = false;
       currentLat = location.getLatitude();
       currentLon = location.getLongitude();
}

    }
```

Comment: Please help me brother. How can I do that in my code. I am really confused. Thank you.

Comment: i have edited my answer, see if it addresses your requirement

Comment: So, how can I get the lastlat and lastlon?

Comment: save them in class variables before assigning the new values.

Comment: before updating the current location, do prevLoc = currentLoc ,and then assign new values to currentLoc. now you have both currentLoc and prevLoc

Comment: Soory brother, I can't understand. Could you please update your answer with this solution. Thx a lot.

Comment: Can you see my edited code? When I run with my edited code it searching gps while location changed. plz help. You can give me full activity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43538/discussion-between-gaurav5430-and-mohammad-rajob)

Answer (score 0):

Because you use:

```
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

set it to null if you want to wait for actual position. then start your jobs from OnLocationChangedListener
that method retreives the last position of the user... GPS takes some time to get the actual position.

**EDIT**

remove this code from the else:

```
                Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if (loc == null) {
                    display.setText("No GPS location found");
                } else {
                    // set Current latitude and longitude
                    currentLon = loc.getLongitude();
                    currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
                    Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);

                }
                // Set the last latitude and longitude
                startStop.setText("Stop");
                lastLat = currentLat;
                lastLon = currentLon;
                doubleclick = true;
```

and just wait for the position instead..display a toast for example, telling the user that you are waiting for the position.
then, when you have the position, do this stuff in the

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
```

method..
I don't know what you're code exactly do...I'm just trying to explain you how I would to this..you have to wait and don't start your operations at the creation of the view, but you have to start everything when you have the position

Comment: How can I do that? plz help me. Thank you.

Comment: I have a button, 2 text view in this application. One text view will show the distance after every 100 miters when walking and another text view only change text (start/stop). When you click the button it will check the gps on device, if the gps disable then it takes user to the gps settings. If enable then the text of the text view will be "stop". And the onLocationChanged method will set the distance in the text view after every 100 meters. When you reach destination and click button second time, it will stop distance calculation and take user to the next activity.

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly I have to do in onLocationChange method?